# Opening internet explorer automation

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a macro which opens Internet Explorer and do lot of things, but when I have sent the Excel file to one co-worker it doesn't work on his computer.

I have cleared everything and try to just open a google webpage but it doesn't work neither.

I have tried:

```
Sub internet()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
With ie

ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate2 "https://www.google.es/"
End With
End Sub
```

I have also tried:

```
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate ("https://www.google.es/")
```

Both work fine for me but not for him. He gets an error of automatization.

Any idea of what can I do?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

the Internet Explorer object library may need to referenced on your co-worker's computer.

Click the "Tools" menu, then references. Then scroll down the list and select `Microsoft HTML Ojbect Library` and `Microsoft Internet Controls`

Comment: If referencing the correct library not resolving the issue then try to provide a error message. It can help us to understand the cause for the issue. Then after we can provide an accurate suggestion to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct references under Tools > References > Microsoft Internet Controls
and Microsoft HTML Object Library?

Also, for your first sample, try declaring `Dim ie as Object` instead of `InternetExplorer`

For more info: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/